# how to change position of label and icon in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components

I have a button in LWC

```
<lightning-button label="Next" icon-name="utility:forward"></lightning-button>
```

It renders as

[image: buton image]

But my requirement is to display the label first and then icon

it should be like Next -> instead of  -> Next

Please suggest if this is possible.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just use [`icon-position="right"`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-button/specification) attribute:

Comment: Thank you so much.